ASP.NET Core 8 Web API endpoints receiving request bodies as null
Using ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, I tried setting up a simple toy example of an API server with some endpoints. Client side, it's a simple React app that queries the endpoints with a fetch request. I don't understand why, but POST/PUT/PATCH endpoints whose methods take input parameters are not getting the data in the request body. It's coming in as null.
I don't have this issue with GET endpoints where the associated methods have inputs. If I change the input type to dynamic instead of string, then it is able receive the request body.
What I tried - server endpoint example:
[HttpPost]
[Route("simplesubmit")]
public void SimpleSubmit([FromBody] string dataAsString)
{
    // simple work
}

Client fetch example:
await fetch ("urlgoeshere.com/simplesubmit", {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({
      name: "my name"
   })
});

What happens: the SimpleSubmit method isn't called, and there's a network response of 400 indicating that the dataAsString field is required.

The real error should be The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. dataAsString shouldn't have type string, it should be of some custom type that will be automatically deserialized from the body.

You are sending a JSON object but method is not a string, you should use this JSON.stringify("my name") instead .


I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.
The request is being sent as application/json but received as string. It doesn't work like that.

To make it work in the way that you can receive any submitted object, you can use dynamic:
[HttpPost]
[Route("simplesubmit")]
// Check out `dynamic` instead of `string`
public void SimpleSubmit([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
    // simple work
}

But that's not the best approach as it doesn't use power of strongly-typed C#.

You should better use a custom-defined class instead.
[HttpPost]
[Route("simplesubmit")]
// Check out the `SubmitRequest` type of the parameter
public void SimpleSubmit([FromBody] SubmitRequest data)
{
    // simple work
}

// Custom class to parse JSON body from a request
public class SubmitRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

data will be automatically parsed from the request body as value of type SubmitRequest.
Just define whatever properties you need in the class SubmitRequest, it will be automatically parsed. But make sure that you provide valid parsable input, otherwise it is going to fail.

Thanks a lot. I'm very new to all of this, so there's still a lot of the ropes for me to see.
